Does the Saha Equation Still Apply if Ions are added Artificially
Suppose I have a hydrogen plasma where some of the electrons have been removed or additional ions have been introduced so the gas has a net non-zero charge density. Would the Saha equation still apply in this case?

Do you mean you have a gas with a net charge?

Since there would be additional ions, there will be a net charge density.

The Saha equation is always something you can use but the level of accuracy is up for debate.  The issue is one of time scales.  If you abruptly introduce charge to a system and don't let it relax then the immediate use of things like the Saha equation will have problems.

What would be a reasonable relaxation time scale for a hydrogen plasma? If the system does have time to relax, would the Saha equation be a reasonable approximation?
